# Office 365 menu shadows in VirtualBox Windows 10 Guest when 3D Acceleration enabled

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, microsoft-office, 3d, ubuntu-22.04

How do I avoid the Office 365 (Microsoft 365) menu shadows with 3D Acceleration enabled? Is 3D Acceleration useful when using Office 365?

**Background**

My Virtualbox is running with a Windows 10 Guest on an Ubuntu 22.02 host. When 3D Acceleration is enabled, there are grey artefacts/shadows in Office 365 (now Microsoft 365) menus.

[image: Office 365 Main Menu shadows]
[image: Office 365 Options Menu shadows]

These shadows make it difficult to use office.

Disabling 'Enable 3D Acceleration' seems to fix this problem.

[image: Enable 3D Acceleration]

Answer (score 1):

3D Acceleration in virtual machines is an optional setting. If it does not work for you on a given machine, disable it.

I have 3 VMs:   2 with 3D ON and one OFF.

For Office, I had to turn 3D OFF in Office a while back for One Note issues. That has since been resolved in Office Updates.  Again, optional, until Office corrects it.

Of course, make sure all Office updates are current and the VM Machine updates are also current.  Windows updates today for Windows 10 and 11.